# In memory cache for Flink (Scala) ? Unable to load Guava

Tags: scala, caching, classpath, guava, apache-flink

I want to use an in-memory cache in my Flink job (Scala), such that I will be able to set a TTL (time to live) for the keys. I have been looking for a solution and found Guava. However, I'm not sure if it works with Flink (v 1.6.3 - Scala) as I'm unable to load any version of Guava in the Flink shell.

```
scala> :require flink-shaded-guava-18.0-6.0.jar
The path 'flink-shaded-guava-18.0-6.0.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.

scala> :require flink-shaded-guava-18.0-5.0.jar
The path 'flink-shaded-guava-18.0-5.0.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.

scala> :require flink-shaded-guava-18.0-4.0.jar
The path 'flink-shaded-guava-18.0-4.0.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.

scala> :require flink-shaded-guava-18.0-3.0.jar
The path 'flink-shaded-guava-18.0-3.0.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.

scala> :require flink-shaded-guava-18.0-2.0.jar
The path 'flink-shaded-guava-18.0-2.0.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.

scala> :require flink-shaded-guava-18.0-1.0.jar
The path 'flink-shaded-guava-18.0-1.0.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.
```

Are there any alternatives? Any helping on resolving this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Flink native keyed state with TTL in FLink 1.6. See here [Flink official doc.](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/state/state.html#raw-and-managed-state).